# Getting total (distinct row) filtered records by paging in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table joined with others and I am getting some rows with paging.

Example:

```
  with cte as
(
SELECT
   -- Users
      U.Id
    , RTRIM(U.[Name]) AS [Name]
    , RTRIM(U.[LastName]) AS [LastName]
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY U.Id) as DENSE

FROM
   dbo.Users U

LEFT JOIN
   dbo.UserLocations UL
ON
   U.Id = UL.UserId

WHERE       
U.[Name] LIKE '%%'

),
cba AS
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cte.Id) AS FilteredRecordsNumber FROM cte
)
SELECT 
    *
    FROM        
    cte,cba
    WHERE
     DENSE > ((@pageNumber-1)*@pageSize) 
    AND
    DENSE <= ((@pageNumber)*@pageSize)
```

I found only that solution that I can see number of records **that I am not getting but there are**.

Since I am using top 1 which I think inefficent, I was wondering if there are any other solutions for getting total filtered records.

**I think that works**
using where clause with dense_rank() worked for me.

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 SUM(COUNT(Id)) OVER()  FROM Users GROUP BY Id?  What does over do?  Top 1 means nothing without a sort.

Comment: Don't use prefix `sp_` for user stored procedures. That prefix is used to designate [system stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql).

Comment: Paparazzi, all columns were same that way I tried TOP 1 there, and thank you Dan, We will rename these one day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total count of records after pagination then, just add this no need of subquery

```
SELECT *,
       FilteredRecordsNumber = Count(1)OVER()
FROM   (SELECT U.Id
        FROM   dbo.Users U
               LEFT JOIN dbo.UserLocations UL
                      ON U.Id = UL.UserId
               LEFT JOIN dbo.Locations L
                      ON L.Id = UL.LocationId
        ORDER  BY Id
        OFFSET ((@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize) ROW FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY) a
```

Comment: but this return number of all records, not filtered one.

Comment: @MEO.. Updated check now.. Remove the top 1  subquery in your query

Comment: @P.. I tried that, but still return number of all records because of joins, It is not distinct or grouped by UserId

Comment: @MEO It will be either pagesize or less than that.  inpossible to get count more than pagesize. Shiw how you have implemented it

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for this posibility.

Comment: @MEO make sure you use the order by and fetch inside the sub-select not in outer query

Comment: yeah, but it is still not distinct number, it is all rows of filter.

Comment: @MEO - Post sample data and expected result